# How to get username from know uid in linux api?

Tags: linux, bash, api, gcc

I am new in `linux`. I need to know user name from given user id in my c application. Is there any `linux api` function available to get this?

Thanks

Comment: try `id [userid]`. for example: `id 0`

Comment: @Kent: Thanks for reply. But when I give id 1000 on command line it shows no such user. But that 1000 is user id listed when I give only id. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with my `id (GNU coreutils) 8.22`. I have id `1000` user too.

Comment: @Kent: what techfun sees seems to be the default in Ubuntu 11,04, 12.04 and 13.04

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to get the username from a c program then `getpwuid` is probably the easiest way.
Man entry here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwnam.3.html

From the command line, I would just grep through passwd:

```
grep 1000 /etc/passwd | cut -f1 -d:
```

Comment: It's better to use `getent passwd` instead of grepping `/etc/passwd` as it works even if the userid is coming from NIS. See [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36580/how-can-i-look-up-a-username-by-id-in-linux) or [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/questions/264986/how-can-i-get-user-name-by-user-id).

Comment: And grepping just `1000` without any anchors will find people with this in their group id or gcos or password or ...